# Equivalent to ms-office-online AUR package

Tags: microsoft-office

Does anyone know whether there is an Ubuntu equivalent to the `ms-office-online` package from the AUR [ms-office-online 20.1.0-2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ms-office-online/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Repology this package is available only for Arch and Manjaro:

- [`ms-office-online`](https://repology.org/project/ms-office-online/versions);
- `ms-office-online`'s dependency - [`jade-application-kit`](https://repology.org/project/python:jade-application-kit/versions)

but you can clone this repository and use the application by steps below:

```
sudo apt install git
#sudo apt install python3-setuptools # for 18.04 LTS
#sudo apt install gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 #GTK Bindings if you are on KDE

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/codesardine/Jade-Application-Kit.git
cd Jade-Application-Kit
sudo python3 ./setup.py install

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://gitlab.manjaro.org/applications/ms-office-online-launcher/tree/a28c813678dfaa5a1923cc6c9e7ef758dfbae8dd
cd ms-office-online-launcher/
sudo make install
```

And then use it with `ms-` prefixed commands:

- `ms-excel`
- `ms-office` - seems to be main Office executable
- `ms-onenote`
- `ms-outlook`
- `ms-powerpoint`
- `ms-skype`
- `ms-word`

or by using menu of your desktop:

> [image: Microsoft Online stuff in menu]

Below is a screenshot for `ms-office` command:

> [image: <code>ms-office</code>]

Tested this method on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS as well as POP!_OS 19.04.

Note that this is using a legacy version of ms-office-online-launcher as the commit from 15 Jun, 2019 broke compatibility.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the great answer and especially the pointer to Repology, I didn't know it. Also the installation worked absolutely fine!

Comment: Possibly oot, but what menu is that on Ubuntu mate part ? Is that addons or anything?

Comment: They are located in Office category. You may need to logout and login again before they appear.

Answer (score 0):

There is a snap package available now: https://snapcraft.io/unofficial-webapp-office

To install it, run the following command in a terminal:

`sudo apt update && sudo snap install unofficial-webapp-office`

If you have not installed snap yet, install it first by running:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install snapd`